# Reputation gain from the last answer displays the daily reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

When navigating to the reputation tab in my profile after not doing so for a while, the latest answer with reputation gain displays the gain for the entire day.

E.g., consider this screenshot - my daily gain (at the time the screenshot was taken) was 30 rep - 20 for the first answer and another 10 for the second. However, the top answer displays +30. Refreshing the page corrects the display.

[image]

Comment: No repro. What you mean "Refreshing the page corrects the display"? So at which point exactly you see the wrong display?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars took the screenshot of the wrong display. Looking back, it seems like you need this to be the first rep gain on that answer for the day. Now when I go back there after visiting that tab for the previous rep gain from that answer it looks correct.

Comment: Sounds like some caching problem then, and pretty esoteric bug overall. If you can reproduce tomorrow with the first answer that will gain rep, it might be more interesting. :)

Comment: Almost certainly a [caching issue](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/), I've seen this issue off and on before and it typically goes away with a refresh or navigating away then coming back.